# Rails Set Resources Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I'm working on rails app and want to keep my javascript as seperated as possible from my backend application logic. I'm planning on using the assets to build an app on top of phonegap later. For my dependencies (javascripts) I'm using bower. I set my bower packages to install at vendor/javascripts but was wondering how I could expose this path to my requirejs-rails calls?

Essentially, what I want to be able to do is require these files in my require-main.js file and have access to them from the rails asset pipeline.

So my code looks something like this

```
vendor/javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js //want to include this
```

requirejs.config {

```
    paths: {

            // following file is located in the vendor/javascripts folder...
        jquery: "javascripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"
    }
}

require ["jquery"], ($) ->


    console.log $
```

Has anyone gotten bower and rails to play nicely together? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is: in the root folder create a file called ".bowerrc" and the content can be the path:

e.g:

```
{
  "directory" : "vendor/plugins"
}
```

after that you should run `bower install` again